# Backup synchronized files with rsync

Tags: rsync

I'm using **`rsync`** to copy a set of files from **A** to **B**. Is it possible to make a backup of only the original files in **B** that are being copied over during the synchronization process? I do not see any option in **`rsync`** for that.

Comment: Are you looking for something like rsync's `--backup-dir` option?

Comment: Indeed that's the `--backup` option I was looking for, simply.